# PHP & ZipArchive() - Falha ao carregar o documento PDF

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf, arquivo-zip

Boa tarde, eu tenho um formulário que em determinado input é aberto uma janela ou múltiplas janelas para exibir um PDF(ou PDF's) específico(s). A pasta onde está o caminho, pode haver apenas um PDF ou um arquivo ZIP com os múltiplos PDF's dentro, de acordo com o valor preenchido no input.

O evento blur () abaixo, é o código que chama as janelas e passa os valores para o "arquivo.php" e "pdf.php". um arquivo é para verificar se é apenas um PDF ou um ZIP, se for um PDF ele retorna para o código javascript, informando que é um PDF apenas, e depois, abre apenas uma janela para mostrar, esta parte está ok.

JavaScript/HTML code:

```
///////////PASSA OS VALORES PARA O "arquivo.php"////////////////
     $.post("arquivo.php", {nprocesso: document.getElementById("processo").value}, function(data){
        $( "#content3" ).html( data ); /*<-- return in this content if is a PDF or a ZIP(when is a zip it returns how many PDF's there are inner ZIP file too)*/

    ////////////ESTA PARTE É PARA CRIAR APENAS UMA JANELA OU MÚLTIPLAS JANELAS, PASSANDO OS VALORES RETORNADOS NO "content3" PARA "pdf.php" PARA EXIBIR O PDF OU OS PDF's//////////////////    
    setTimeout(function(){
               if(document.getElementById("content3").innerText == "PDF"){
                  window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); 
               }else{
                  var QuantPDF = Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.lastIndexOf(','))+1, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length));//Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
                  var NomesPDFS = []; NomesPDFS = document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(3, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length-2).split(',');
                  if(QuantPDF > 1){
                   for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){
                    window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value+"/"+NomesPDFS[i], '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");  
                   }   
                  }else{
                   window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");    
                  }
               }
              document.getElementById('closeBtn').click();
              }, 1000);
            }
```

Este é o "arquivo.php", onde verifica se é apenas um arquivo PDF ou ZIP, e extrai se for um zip.

Arquivo.php code:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  //////////ESTA PARTE VERIFICA SE O ARQUIVO É UM PDF E RETORNAR AO MEU CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT/////////
  if(file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'.pdf')){

    echo 'PDF';
    $_SESSION['file'] = "PDF";

  }else{

//////////ESTA PARTE VERIFICA SE O ARQUIVO É UM ZIP E RETORNAR AO MEU CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT/////////

    echo 'ZIP';
    $_SESSION['file'] = "ZIP";
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
     $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'.zip';
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      if($zip->open($path) === true){
       //////////THIS PART IT OPENS THE ZIP AND EXTRACT/////////
if(!file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'])){
            mkdir('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'], 0777, true);
           }
            for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++){
             $zip->extractTo('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'], array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
             $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'];
             $files = scandir($path); array_shift($files); array_shift($files);
             $file = array(); $filename = array();
        ///////AGORA PEGO OS NOMES DOS PDF's E A QUANTIDADE DE PARA E VOLTO AO CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT///////
             $file[$i] = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'/'.$files[$i];
             $filename[$i] = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'/'.$files[$i];
             $nomes_pdfs = array();
             $nomes_pdfs[$i] = substr(substr($filename[$i], strpos($filename[$i], $_POST['nprocesso'])+26, strlen($filename[$i])), 0, strpos(substr($filename[$i], strpos($filename[$i], $_POST['nprocesso'])+26, strlen($filename[$i])), '.pdf')).',';
             echo $nomes_pdfs[$i];
            }               
           $zip->close();

           $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'];
           $files = scandir($path);
           array_shift($files); array_shift($files); $_SESSION['quantidade_pdf'] = count($files);
           echo $_SESSION['quantidade_pdf'];
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Meu problema é, na verdade, parcialmente em "pdf.php", onde a janela é carregada com os valores retornados do "content3". Como disse anteriormente, quando é um único PDF, a janela é exibida normalmente, mas quando é um arquivo ZIP com múltiplos PDF's, o primeiro PDF é exibido corretamente, mas a partir do segundo em diante, ele não é exibido. mostre este erro: "Falha ao carregar o documento PDF".

pdf.php code:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf') && is_file('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf')){
 $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
 $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 @readfile($file);
}else{
/////////////////////AQUI ESTÁ A PARTE QUANDO É UM ZIP////////////////////////
///////*Esta parte é apenas para verificar se o extração da pasta foi feita e ela existe*/////////
 function folder_exist($folder){ $path = realpath($folder); return ($path !== false AND is_dir($path)) ? $path : false; }
 chdir('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/');
 $folder = '/'.substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/')).'/';
 if(FALSE !== ($path = folder_exist($folder))){
 /////*Aqui começa a parte onde o código pega os PDF's e os exibe*/////
  $pasta = substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/'));
  $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
  $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
 }else{
  die('<h2 style="background-color:#FA5858"><center>Não foi encontrado a inicial do processo. Verifique se o mesmo encontra-se na pasta.</center></h2>');
 }
}
?>
```

O que estou fazendo errado? Eu já verifiquei a pasta, o nome do arquivo, o endereço para pasta, está tudo certo. Não consigo ver o que está ocasionando este erro